# How to close my browser after each test in a suite for protractor?

Tags: protractor, suite

I was trying to run my tests as a suite. There are three tests in a suite, how can I make my browser close after each test ?

```
suites:
        {
          one: 'one.js',
          two: 'two.js',
          three: 'three.js'
        };
```

The problem is that each of this test is used to load a separate url, and each test checks whether the correct url is loaded. But my test fails each time as all the urls are different.

Comment: Set restartBrowserBetweenTests: true in your config file. This will slow your tests down though.

Comment: That makes my browser to open and close even when the test is over

Comment: Could you give some more details of whats happening?

Answer (score 5):

You can use below method in you spec.js

```
afterEach(() => {
         browser.close(); (or browser.driver.close();)
        console.log('afterEach');
    });
```

Comment: `restartBrowserBetweenTests` option is specifically designed for this.

Comment: exports.config = {
    restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
    }

Yes this will also work

Comment: @FCin Thank you so much!